# Hearing static from front audio port on soundcard

Tags: audio, sound-card

I recently bought an Asus Xonar 5.1 DG soundcard. I have connected my front audio to the soundcard header, the problem is though, when I use my headphones in the front jack I hear static when the volume is loud enough. However when it is plugged straight into the soundcard on the back, it's silent.

I expected it to be the same quality when it was in either the front or the back.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a faulty jack or connection on the device (as we know the headphones are fine) - I would contact the manufacturer as you've bought it recently.

Answer (score 1):

Could be that the connector that goes from the front of your comp into your motherboard isn't connected 100% or a certain part of the wire is touching something that's causing static (not sure how much this happens inside a pc).  I'd follow the wires from the front to the board and make sure you don't have a cat hanging off them or something like that +D